# Can you help me identify this creature?

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures

I bought this necklace recently which had no info about the creature on it. I was just wondering if it's just made up or if it features in any myths/legends? Thanks[image: humanoid creature with insect-like wings. long protruding nose, no facial features. holds a staff. is wading with trousers rolled up through a grassy field or water. an eye is in the sky above it.]

Answer (score 6):

It's Saint Christopher.

[image]

https://www.cassandragoad.com/jewellery/pendants-charms/extra-large-st-christopher-gold-pendant

(For that one down voting: you're right, thank you & pardon me: )

[image]

That was fun to figure out, thanks.

The best, W.D.S